# Is there a PowerShell DSC module for Azure AD Application Registrations?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, dsc

Is there a PowerShell DSC module for Azure AD Application Registrations?  I've googled extensively and so far the best bet for configuring the registrations is the [Azure AD 2.0 PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#applications) - this does not address my question as it is not a desired state module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, DSC is not supported in Azure AD Registrations, it is supported in Azure just through the [Azure Desired State Configuration extension handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-overview) and through [Azure Automation DSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-overview).

For more details, refer to this article: [Using DSC on Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/azuredsc).

If you want to improve it, you could give your feedback in the [comments-container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/azuredsc#comments-container).